# Unable to send mail from Java application

Tags: java, email

In my java application I need to send mails to different mail addresses. I am using the next piece of code , but for some reason  it doesn't work.

```
public class main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.yahoo.com.");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");  

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new MyAuth());  

        try {  
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("giginnho@yahoo.com"));  
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress("rantravee@yahoo.com")};  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);  
            msg.setSubject("subject ");  
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());  

            msg.setText("Message here ");  

            Transport.send(msg);  
        }  catch (MessagingException e) {}  
    } 

}  

class MyAuth extends Authenticator {  
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
        return new PasswordAuthentication("my username","my password");  
    }
}
```

I get the folowing text from debuging it:

```
[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com.au.", port 25, isSSL false
```

Could anyone inform me , what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just FYI, your code will be more testable and more flexible if you code against Spring's MailSender API rather than the core JavaMail API. For example, you don't end up with untestable static calls like "Transport.send(msg)".

Comment: As a rule, it's a good idea to at least print out your exceptions, especially when debugging ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I faced the same problem when sending mail using a gmail id, you are using yahoo. The problem was gmail uses ssl layer protection, i think same is the case with yahoo so you need to use

```
mail.smtps.host instead of mail.smtp.host
```

and same for other properties too.

and isSSL to true.

I can post complete code snippet, once i reach office and use office's machine. For now you can look at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0570.html

Comment: please add the solution of your problem to your description - this allows others in your situation to see the answer directly.

Comment: The link in the above post took me to an example that worked !

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo! Mail SMTP server address: smtp.mail.yahoo.com 
Yahoo! Mail SMTP user name: Your full Yahoo! Mail email address (including "@yahoo.com")
Yahoo! Mail SMTP password: Your Yahoo! Mail password
Yahoo! Mail SMTP port: 465
Yahoo! Mail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

Similar settings work with gmail. For yahoo you might need yahoo plus account

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your ISP blocking port 25 traffic (not unusual!)

From http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-32.html:

> In an attempt to control unsolicited email (spam), some Internet service providers now block port 25, which means you could experience technical problems when sending email. If you are having trouble sending email, you may need to use port 465 (recommended) or 587 when sending email via Yahoo!'s SMTP server.